# Dagger2 Inject all instances of a type

Tags: java, dagger-2

Using Dagger2, I am creating a large number of command types:

```
interface Command {
  void execute();
}

@Named("commandImpl")
class CommandImpl
  @Inject
  public CommandImpl() {
  }
}
```

I then want inject all of the command instances by name into another class:

```
@Inject Map<String, Command> commands;
```

I've seen how I can wire all of this up using multibinding with a `Module` and `Produces`, but for a significant number of command objects it seems like a lot of boilerplate to wire up all the commands and their dependencies by hand. Is there an easier way to do this?